# Non-manifold seam?

Tags: modeling

Im trying to model Oogway from Kung Fu Panda, and Im having an issue with his shell. Im using a mirror modifier to create a symmetrical shell, but it seems that the seam in the middle of the shell is non-manifold. I tried using the "merge by distance" tool to no avail. I need the entire model to be one printable model, but since the shell is non-manifold I cant use the "Union" modifier.

Comment: Make sure you have "Clip" and "Merge" turned on in the Mirror Modifier, then make sure all your mid-line vertices lie on the plane of symmetry, e.g. x = 0

Comment: also make sure you haven't created an inner face